# Retrieving Azure Docker host logs

Tags: azure, docker, logging

I have been running a single container .net core web app on Azure using their preview single-container service for a couple of months.

It runs fine and Azure diligently proxies requests to the container from the web as expected - albeit with an important caveat.

What it doesn't do, to my chargrin, is proxy the requester's IP address to the container directly, it does this via an additional http header. This means that the backend code, which uses Application Insights for telemetry, is capturing the proxy's IP address (0.0.0.0) instead of the originating client's IP address.

This is clearly an oversight and is addressable via a pull request (since the Application Insights code is open source) - the problem I have is I'm missing important IP address information.

Does anyone know if there's a way to obtain this **retrospective** request/log data (at host level) from the Azure Portal?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the originating client's IP address in the Azure Web App?

Comment: The flow looks like this:  (1) Client --> (2) Azure Proxy (Docker Host) --> (3) My app (Docker Container).  I do want the originating IP address (1), but Application Insights is reporting the IP address of the azure proxy host (2) - which is understandable, but not correct.  The IP address for (1) is accessible to (3) via a forwarded http header - although this doesn't help me with the events already captured.  I have no doubt Microsoft are logging client IPs at host/proxy level (2) - but I don't know if those are available to me as an end user in the portal or not...  HTH!